# Not able to acces internet in an Ubuntu Guest in a Windows host using Oracle VIrtual Box

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

My Machine is a WIndows 7 enterprise edition.

The network in my institution is setup in such a way that Mac Addesses have to be registered in the system to work.

I installed the plain and vanilla flavor of VM Virtualbox and installed Ubuntu 14.04, and noticed that it has a different MAC address.

I'm Using the NAT controller, and it does not seem to work either.

Thanks

Comment: Contact your IT administrator. You're effectively trying to add a new device to their network, and it seems that they would like to be made aware of such things. I'm sure they can help guide you through the proper processes required for your organization.

Comment: Isn't there a way to piggyback on the network access that the host already has?

Comment: There are a number of ways your IT department may be monitoring and/or filtering network traffic that could prevent this regardless of how the VM NIC is configured. (1:) We're not going to help you circumvent your organization's IT Security policy. (2:) Even if we would, it's highly doubtful that you'll be able to provide the kind of information needed to do so without someone from your organization's IT department noticing what you're trying to do - and that could end in some unpleasant conversations for you.

Comment: Actually I was not trying to do anything shady, is just that before I asked here, I asked them and they told me I should be able to connect to the network directly, which indicated me they might not be sure about how to setup VMs either.

Comment: Have you tried using a Bridged adapter, and registering the VM's MAC?

Comment: I would not be sure on how to do that, by registering you mean with the IT people?

Comment: Yes. You said all MAC addresses need to be registered. Register the VM's MAC with the IT people and switch the NIC to "Bridged Mode" (same place where you saw it set as NAT, change NAT to Bridged and double-check that the MAC stays the same as the one you've registered or will register). This will make the VM behave on the network as if it is a completely separate device from the host.

Comment: When I get home, I'll take some screenshots and post an answer. Please up-vote and accept if it works. If it doesn't, maybe we can come up with something else. Or try asking a different IT guy in your institution - it's a fair bet that someone over there uses virtual machines and has at least half an idea of what should work on their network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your virtual machine settings, select Network on the left side.
2. Then choose the appropriate adapter from the tabs on the right.
3. Make sure the adapter is enabled, then choose "Bridged Adapter" from the "Attached to" drop-down.
4. From the "Name" drop-down, choose the host system adapter you want to bind the VM NIC to. You may want to create multiple VM NICs to bridge to each host adapter, or you will need to manually swap the adapter binding if your host configuration changes (e.g.: Moving a host laptop from a wired to a wireless network.)
5. If the "Advanced" section isn't showing, click the triangle to the left of it to expand it.
6. Note down the MAC Address and make sure the cable is connected. (If you created multiple bridged VM NICs, you'll need to make sure the MACs are unique, and note down each.)
7. Also double-check that the "Adapter Type" is compatible with the guest OS (usually not a problem with defaults).
8. The "Promiscuous Mode" setting depends on the host system's capabilities, and what you want the guest to be able to do. Most people are fine leaving it disabled, and some configurations actually won't allow you to enable it.
9. Send the MAC addresses for each bridged VM NIC to your network administrators.
10. When the network administrators have informed you that their infrastructure is configured to permit access to those MAC addresses, boot the VM and try it out.

Here's a screenshot of the relevant section in the VirtualBox VM Settings dialog.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer, I just asked them, and they seem adamant on not registering virtual MAC addresses.

Comment: Hi Again, I'm going to accept your question but leave this as future reference.
In my system, we use Sophos antivirus, which apparently has conflicts with VM virtual box, I tried Vmware and it ran on the first try, without changing any setting.
Thanks!!